# Change grails hasMany from LinkedHashSet to ArrayList

Tags: grails, arraylist, grails-orm, has-many, linkedhashset

I have the following:

```
class A{

    static hasMany = [b: B]
}
```

Grails generates the class with property b being a `LinkedHashMap`.  I want to configure Grails in order to generate an `ArrayList` instead.

I know this can be done by explicitly writing the list:

```
class A{

    static hasMany = [b: B]

    List<B> b = new ArrayList<B>()
}
```

But I was looking for a way to achieve this by some external configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not configurable - The only solution is to declare a property of the type list as you did in your sample.